How to write common step def for Android and iOS when the locators are different for both and value is passed from feature file
I have a situation where
For example:
Android locator is having account number 6 1 8 8
iOS is having account number as 6188
All my steps are same only the account number locator is different which I am passing it from a feature file. How can I write a code which works for both.
This is because I am not hardcoding the locator in my locators java file. Am passing it from feature file.
